# php mysql : Could not load data from file into table

Tags: php, mysql

Need your help, I got this error message when i try to load data in mysql table
It don't have problems when using phpMAdmin import tab.
Error message when I run the script bellow: Could not load data from file into table

Regards

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "Sam007";
$password   = "****";
$dbname     = "MyDB";
$TZ         =  date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");
$conn       =  new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$file = '/home/epchgnpdqsbm/public_html/locataire.csv';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo "Data file found ", 'locataire.csv' . "<br>";
} 
else {
    echo "file locataire.csv not found" . "<br>";
}

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else {
    echo "Connexion to database " . $dbname . ' ' . 'success <br>';
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locataire (
id_locataire int(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
immeuble varchar(10) NOT NULL,
unite varchar(10) NOT NULL,
nom varchar(20) NOT NULL,
prenom varchar(20) NOT NULL,
email varchar(40) NOT NULL,
transmis boolean,
consenti boolean,
date_acceptation datetime
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET='latin1'";

$maketable = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$maketable) {
    die('Could not create table: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql= "LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
    INTO TABLE locataire
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (id_locataire,immeuble,unite,nom,prenom,email,transmis,consenti,date_acceptation)";

$loaddata = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$loaddata) {
    die('Could not load data from file into table: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like your query is failing, so you need to get the actual error.  `$conn->connect_error` tells you about *connection* errors, not *query* errors.  Get the query error: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: try running that query on whatever client you use to see what happens or echo the query error as suggested above.

Comment: Hi,
This the mysql error: 
"Access denied for user 'Hakim'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I can't Grant any privilege with Godaddy user 'epchgnpdqsbm'

Comment: The Tab Users/Privileges is missing in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Solved, I had to add this line into my php script:                   
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);                                    Many thanks